# How to Fill a Cell Depending on a Drop-Down List

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering if there was a way to fill in a cell depending on the choice a user makes in a drop down list. For simplicity sake, I'll use an analogous situation to the one I'm facing.

Right now I have a drop down list in one cell, so like you can choose from Dog, Cat, Bird, and Frog. Then I have Column A with 30 entries, a mixture of those four animals. What I want to do is: when a person goes to the drop down list and chooses, say Cat, all the entries in Column A that match Cat are filled with a color. If they change their choice in the drop down list to Frog, then only entries in Column A that match Frog will be filled.

Is there a way to do this? I'm semi-familiar with conditional formatting and I feel like there's a way to do it with custom formulas, but I haven't messed with those yet. Any help you guys could give would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.  Use **Insert > Note** to describe what you want in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) rule like this:

```
Value is equal to:
=$A$1
```

...where `A1` is the location of the drop-down list cell.

This will color the cells that match cell `A1` with a color — always the same color. To use different colors for Cat, Dog, Frog, use several custom formula rules that compare a formatted cell to the drop-down list cell.